# Fixes for "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal"

Tags: c, enums, strtok, unhandled-exception

I am trying to parse through a .csv file with the format as such

Patient,minute,calories,distance,floors,heart,steps,sleep_level

The line is modified previously so that empty values in the line (a ,,) get changed to ,-1, and there is a comma thrown in the end before that so if sleep_level is empty it too gets a -1 value.

```
            strcpy(data[i].patient, strtok(line, ",")); 
            //Detect for correct patient
            if (data[i].patient == patient) {
                printf("Wrong patient, skiping data");
            }
            else {
                //Minute (string)
                strcpy(data[i].minute, strtok(NULL, ","));
                if (i != 0 && strtok(NULL, ",") == data[i - 1].minute) {
                }
                else {

                    //Calories (double)
                    data[i].calories = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                    //Distance (double)
                    data[i].distance = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                    //Floors(unsigned int)
                    data[i].floors = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
                    //Heart Rate(unsigned int)
                    data[i].heartRate = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
                    //Steps(unsigned int)
                    data[i].steps = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));

                    //Sleep level (enumertated var)
                    int sleepLvl = atoi(strtok(NULL, ",")); <-BREAKS HERE
                    if (sleepLvl == 0 || sleepLvl == -1) {
                        data[i].sleepLevel = NONE;
                    }
                    else if (sleepLvl == 1) {
                        data[i].sleepLevel = ASLEEP;
                    }
                    else if (sleepLvl == 2) {
                        data[i].sleepLevel = AWAKE;
                    }
                    else {
                        data[i].sleepLevel = REALLYAWAKE;
                    }

                    //Increment the index
                    i++;
                }
```

This code uses tokens to the commas withing the parsed lines to pull out the information one section at a time an place them into an array of structs to store all the data. it should be noted that sleep_level is an ENUM but I think the way I handled it is correct.

The code breaks at the <-breaks here with an unhandled exception: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

an example formatted line for this data would be 
12cx7,0:01:00,0.968900025,-1,0,67,0,1,

what should I be using in strtok (What I believe is the source of the error) to parse that last value correctly?

Comment: `atoi(strtok(NULL, ","))` this looks extremely dangerous, in all cases. Did you check if `strtok(NULL, ",")` is returning NULL?

Comment: Always check return values. Consider a [mcve] with input that causes the crash. You might want to just step through the code in a debugger and see if you can figure out where it goes wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, there was issues earlier in the program with comparing strings of code